# Add Product into cart and get it in another Activity

Tags: android

I want to implement cart function when user clicks on plus or minus btn of item that item should be saved some where and if he clicked on same item again then only quantity have to updated not all the item of list. It means on clicking plus btn json object of that item will be saved in shard preference but again when same item clicked only quantity will updated not whole json object.

```
public class ItemListNewAdap extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListNewAdap.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<PromotionModel> moviesList;
    int ii=-1;
    Context context;
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, quantity, price,newprice,num;
        public Button btnIncrease,btnDecrease;
        ImageView mitemimg;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mitemimg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.griddetail_text);
            quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_text);
            price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_text);
            newprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newprice_text);
            num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num_text);
            btnIncrease =view.findViewById(R.id.plus_text);
            btnDecrease = view.findViewById(R.id.minus_text);
        }
    }

    public ItemListNewAdap(Context context,List<PromotionModel> moviesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.menusubitemlayout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final PromotionModel movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getHeading());
        holder.price.setText(movie.getOldprice());
        holder.newprice.setText(movie.getNewprice());
        holder.quantity.setText(movie.getQuantity());

        Picasso.with(context).load(movie.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.download).error(R.drawable.download).into(holder.mitemimg);


        holder.btnIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                ii++;

                int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.num.getText()));
                count++;
                holder.num.setText(String.valueOf(count));

                // ii++;
                // holder.num.setText(ii+"");
               notifyDataSetChanged();

               String chk = moviesList.get(position).getChk();

               try {
                        JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();

                        student1.put("pid", moviesList.get(position).getItemid());
                        student1.put("desc", moviesList.get(position).getDetailtxt());
                        student1.put("imgurl", moviesList.get(position).getImage());
                        student1.put("name", moviesList.get(position).getHeading());
                        student1.put("newprice", moviesList.get(position).getNewprice());
                        student1.put("oldprice", moviesList.get(position).getOldprice());
                        student1.put("quantity", moviesList.get(position).getQuantity());
                        student1.put("unit", count);

                        jsonArray.put(student1);

                        Log.d("nlononnono", "" + jsonArray.toString());

                        // SharedPreferences sharedPrefotp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefcart", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        // SharedPreferences.Editor editor123 = sharedPrefotp.edit();
                        // editor123.putString("quantity", jsonArray.toString());
                        // editor123.commit();
                        //       ((HomeActivity)activity).mcounttxt.setText(String.valueOf(ii));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        });

        holder.btnDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                int count= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(holder.num.getText()));

                if(count > 0) {
                    // 2. enter code here
                    count--;

                    holder.num.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                }

                // ii--;
                // holder.num.setText(ii+"");
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                try {
                    JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();

                    student1.put("pid", moviesList.get(position).getItemid());
                    student1.put("desc", moviesList.get(position).getDetailtxt());
                    student1.put("imgurl", moviesList.get(position).getImage());
                    student1.put("name", moviesList.get(position).getHeading());
                    student1.put("newprice", moviesList.get(position).getNewprice());
                    student1.put("oldprice", moviesList.get(position).getOldprice());
                    student1.put("quantity", moviesList.get(position).getQuantity());
                    student1.put("unit", count);

                    jsonArray.put(student1);

                    Log.d("nlononnono", "" + jsonArray.toString());


                    // Log.d("nlononnono", "" + jsonArray.toString());

//                    SharedPreferences sharedPrefotp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefcart", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor123 = sharedPrefotp.edit();
//                    editor123.putString("quantity", jsonArray.toString());
//                    editor123.commit();

                    //       ((HomeActivity)activity).mcounttxt.setText(String.valueOf(ii));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last year i had similar requirements for one of my project. I solved it by storing data using Sharedpreferences and any other activity can basically have access to it. Here is my code with two main functions I used to add and removed products from the cart. In your case you can simply modify the add function to  specify whether it's a plus or a minus sign button that was pressed to add or remove the product from the list

```
public class Product{
   public int id;
   public double price;
   public String name;
   public int quantity;
}

public class Storage{
   Context mContext;
   public Storage(Context context){
     mContext = context;
   }

   //get your saved cart
   public ArrayList<Product> getCartList(){
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = sharedPref.getString(ReferenceDataEnums.Cart.name(), null);
     Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType();
     return gson.fromJson(json, type);
   }

   public void addToCart(Product product){
       ArrayList<Product> products = getCartList();

       if (products == null){
         //Cart is empty. Therefore product does not exist in the cart
         products = new ArrayList<>();
         products.add(product);
       }
       else{
         boolean productExists = false;
         while (iterator.hasNext())
         {
            if(iterator.next().id.equals(product.id))
            {
               //Increment current quantity
               productExists = true;
               break;
            }
         }

         if(productExists)
         {
           iterator.next().quantity++;
         }
         else{
           //Product does not exist in the cart
           products = new ArrayList<>();
           products.add(product);
         }
       }

       SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

       Gson gson = new Gson();
       Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>(){}.getType();
       String json = gson.toJson(products, type);
       editor.putString(ReferenceDataEnums.Cart.name(), json);
       editor.apply();
   }
}
```

Hope it helps